# Recyclerview cannot be scrolled?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="DoUpload"
        android:text="Sync with server"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this (which is OK):

[image]

So I add more datas, now it looks like this:

[image]

The RecyclerView cannot be scrolled, and the button is hidden. How to fix this?

Comment: Use Constraints or RelativeLayout as root to make button visiible . And i think its not scrolling because it has only 5 items if you did not consume touch event .

Comment: set android:layout_weight="1" to your RelativeLayout which have RecyclerView
your issue will solved

Comment: @Arbaz.in Wow this works. Thank you. But I wonder why it works, though?

Comment: @anta40 because we set android:layout_weight="1
that means RelativeLayout  occupied the space of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sync"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="DoUpload"
        android:text="Sync with server"/>
    </LinearLayout >
</LinearLayout>
```

just copy this code and use it will be working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
I have edited the code for you this will solve the problem and button will be at the end of RecyclerView    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sync"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="DoUpload"
                    android:text="Sync with server" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_sync"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="DoUpload"
        android:text="Sync with server"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using constraint layout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_sync"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:onClick="DoUpload"
        android:text="Sync with server" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This layout should keep the button from hiding and recyclerview will scroll when more data items are added.

Answer (score 0):

used nestedScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `NestedScrollView` is not a solution . This will only complicate the thing.